# When is a Custom Element constructor invoked? (HTMLTemplateElement.content problem)

Tags: javascript, constructor, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

Take a look at this simple example
*(don't bother with this, go to the EDIT)*

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {

  customProperty = "something";

  constructor() {
    super();

    console.log("My Element Constructor");
  }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);

document.body.innerHTML = "<my-element></my-element>";
var myElement = document.querySelector("my-element");
console.log(myElement); // 
console.log(myElement.customProperty); //
```

The output:

```
<my-element>
undefined
My Element Constructor
```

The custom element constructor it is not called (but the HTMLElement constructor it is) until the main call stack is done. Is this an expected behavior or a bug?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

In an attempt to simplify my real case, I proposed the previous example, which I now see is not appropriate to illustrate my problem (the example does work correctly). Thanks to @connexo's answer I was able to isolate the problem (it's a complex project with many dependencies) and translate it to the following example:

```js
class SubElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log("Sub Element Constructor");
    }
}

customElements.define("sub-element", SubElement);

class MainElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

        let template = document.createElement("template");
        
        template.innerHTML = "<sub-element></sub-element>";

        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content);

        // The above line doesn't call the Sub Element constructor
        // But the bellow line does it

        // this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<sub-element></sub-element>";

        console.log("Main Element Constructor");
    }
}

customElements.define("main-element", MainElement);

var myElement = document.createElement("main-element");

// Sub Component constructor will not be called until
// the parent element is added to the DOM (next line)
// document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

For some reason, when the **content** of a **template** element is added to a shadowRoot, these elements will not be parsed until the shadowRoot is added to the DOM.
But when the innerHTML of the shadowRoot is modified directly, this content is parsed even when the shadowRoot does not belong to the DOM.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is your script? Did you put it in the head tag?

Comment: innerHTML is wrong, you have to use DOM or wait till my-element exist... Use document.createElement instead.

Comment: Your code snippet is logging fine for me, but not in the order you've described.

Comment: Your problem is not related to anything with the main call stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Q: When is a Custom Element constructor invoked?

### A: In three situations:

1. If your element is registered in the custom elements registry *before* the element gets parsed, its constructor is called when parsing the `<my-element` part of the HTML. Notice the missing `>` - for this case this is all the parser has parsed when calling the constructor - **no attributes, no children**).
2. If your element is *not yet registered* in the custom elements registry before the element gets parsed, the constructor gets called right after your custom element registration is done. This is called the *upgrade* case. Before the upgrade, your custom element to the browser is just an `HTMLUnknownElement`.
3. The constructor is also called when you dynamically create your custom element using either `new MyElement()` or `document.createElement('my-element')`. Notice that a) in both cases neither attributes nor children exist and b) when creating the element using `document.createElement('my-element')` the point in time of calling the constructor will be either 1. or 2. (depending on if the custom element has already been registered or not).

Your code will work as expected as long as you make sure it doesn't run before `document.body` is available.

The easiest way to achieve this is to include your script only immediately before the closing `</body>` tag.

An easy alternative, if your JS is in an external file, is to include it using the boolean attribute `defer`:

```
<script src="./path/to/my/script.js" defer></script>
```

A 2nd alternative is to wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener (this way it doesn't matter where you put the `script` tag and you also don't need a `defer` attribute):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    
      customProperty = "something";
    
      constructor() {
        super();
    
        console.log("My Element Constructor");
      }
    }
    
    customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
    
    document.body.innerHTML = "<my-element></my-element>";
    var myElement = document.querySelector("my-element");
    console.log(myElement); // 
    console.log(myElement.customProperty); //

});
```

All three methods basically enforce the upgrade case (2.) which in years of professional practice with authoring large web component libraries has proven to be both the most reliable and the most simple approach.

### Edit

Since you've now totally changed your question, here's the answer to that:

> The `<template>` HTML element is a mechanism for holding HTML **that is not to be rendered immediately** when a page is loaded **but may be instantiated subsequently during runtime using JavaScript**.

> Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for subsequent use in the document. While the parser does process the contents of the `<template>` element while loading the page, **it does so only to ensure that those contents are valid; the element's contents are not rendered, however.**

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

and

> However, the `HTMLTemplateElement` has a content property, which is a read-only `DocumentFragment` containing the DOM subtree which the template represents. **Note that directly using the value of the content could lead to unexpected behavior**, see Avoiding DocumentFragment pitfall section below.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#attributes

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to identify and isolate my problem. I edited my question.

Comment: Also I added an answer with a possible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `<template>` has **nothing** to do with it.

`innerHTML` is **synchronous**, It is `append`(child) that adds content **A-synchronous**

So in the examples below,

- `.innerHTML` is parsed immediatly
- The remainder of the `constructor` is executed;
  only *after* that the `append` content is parsed.
- Using a `<style onload>` Event to show WHEN code is parsed
- 2 `<div>`s to check when lightDOM (`this.children.length`) IS parsed

```html
<script>
customElements.define("sub-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();console.log("Sub Element Constructor");
  }
  connectedCallback(){
  let maindivcount = () => this.parentNode.children.length;
  console.log("connectedCallback",this,maindivcount());
    setTimeout(()=>console.log("parsed!",this,maindivcount()));
  }
});
customElements.define("main-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Main Element Constructor START");

    let style = Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {
      onload: () => console.log("<style> loaded in ", this,this.children.length)
    });
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = "<sub-element></sub-element>"; // SYNCHRONOUS!

    this.shadowRoot.append(style); // A-SYNC!!

    console.log("Main Element Constructor END");
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    console.log("connectedCallback",this,this.children.length);
    setTimeout(()=>console.log("parsed!",this,this.children.length));
  }
});
</script>

<main-element><div></div><div></div></main-element>
```

##### With `createElement`

```js
customElements.define("sub-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("Sub Element Constructor");
  }
});

customElements.define("main-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Main Element Constructor START");

    let style = Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {
      onload: () => console.log("<style> loaded in ", this)
    });

    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = "<sub-element></sub-element>"; // SYNCHRONOUS!

    this.shadowRoot.append(style); // A-SYNC!!

    console.log("Main Element Constructor END");
  }
});

var myElement = document.createElement("main-element");
console.log("before append");
document.body.append(myElement);
```

Comment: I don't think appendChild is async. What is asynchronous is the loading of the content of the style element. But not all elements load its contents asynchronous (just img, body, script and link I think)

Comment: Can you back it up with code or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I select as correct the @connexo's answer for the comprehensiveness of the explanation. But here is how I resolve my issue.
If you need to replicate the functionality of the Template element and his Content property, but also need that the HTML parsed content instanciates inmediatly the custom elements in it, use the next method:

```
function HTMLToFragment(html) {

    let divTemplate = document.createElement("div");
    divTemplate.innerHTML = html;

    let fragment = new DocumentFragment();

    fragment.prepend(...divTemplate.childNodes);

    return fragment;

}
```

And here, using this technique, the solution to my question:

```js
class SubElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log("Sub Element Constructor");
    }
}

customElements.define("sub-element", SubElement);

class MainElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

        let divTemplate = document.createElement("div");
        divTemplate.innerHTML = "<sub-element></sub-element>";

        let fragment = new DocumentFragment();

        fragment.prepend(...divTemplate.childNodes);                

        this.shadowRoot.append(fragment);

        console.log("Main Element Constructor");
    }
}

customElements.define("main-element", MainElement);

var myElement = document.createElement("main-element");
```

Comment: Yes, ``DocumentFragment`` saves your butt in this edge-case. But you are now stuck with a container ``<div>`` in shadowDOM. You might want to do: ``.append(...fragment.firstChild.childNodes)`` instead of that oldskool FOR loop