# How to provide callbacks to a Custom Element

Tags: javascript, callback, custom-element, native-web-component

I decided to try my hand at creating a native web component by writing a [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements).

```js
export default class DropDown extends HTMLElement {
...
```

Once I got everything in place, it seemed to be working fine. But then I decided to add some callback hooks so the application could respond to events on the component.

The logical place to add them is in the constructor, right?

```js
 /**
   * 
   * @param {Object} callbacks
   * @param {Function} callbacks.itemSelected 
   * @param {Function} callbacks.dropDownClicked
   */
  constructor(callbacks = {}) {
    super();
    if (callbacks) this.#callbacks = callbacks;
  }

  #handleItemSelected(selection) {
    console.log('handleItemSelected()');
    if (this.#callbacks.itemSelected) this.#callbacks.itemSelected(this, selection);
    if (this.#displaySelection) this.#valuePara.textContent = selection;
  }
```

And then in my application code:

```js
function demoHandler(thisVal, selection) {
    console.log('demoHandler ' + thisVal + ' ' + selection);
}

new DropDown({ itemSelected: demoHandler });
```

But the callback wasn't getting executed. I figured out that `this.#callbacks` was empty. So I logged the various method/function calls. Here's the order they're executed in:

```
constructor()
attributeChangedCallback()
connectedCallback()
constructor()
<user click>
handleItemSelected()
```

Wow. `constructor()` is called by the Custom Element framework. When my app code calls it again later, it's pointless because the object my app constructs isn't the object being used by the framework. Moreover, there's no way for the application to get the object ref from the framework's instantiation. Without that object reference, I don't know how I can pass in callback functions for the object to execute.

How can I add these callbacks to my object?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717100/when-is-a-custom-element-constructor-invoked-htmltemplateelement-content-probl) help?

Comment: @BoppreH it illuminates what's going on under the hood, but it doesn't address my design problem. Thanks for sharing it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I approached this issue is by creating public methods on the class. You can then query the element and call the custom method directly.

Here's a simplified example of what I mean. The following class definition has a `changeToRed` function that can be called directly, because it's just an object property like any other.

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  changeToRed() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<p>I'm a custom element.</p>`
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-element", CustomElement);
```

To access this method, let's first create an instance of the custom element in HTML and assign it an `id`.

```html
<custom-element id="custom-element"></custom-element>
```

Now, we can access that custom element via the DOM and use the public method.

```js
const customEl = document.getElementById('custom-element');
customEl.changeToRed();
```

See the working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/joshschroder/pen/OJGJwpq).

Also, FWIW, I really think it's better to use a framework with Custom Elements. You certainly don't have to, but it's going to make your life much easier if you're building anything of any complexity. I started out with vanilla JS/TS, then moved onto using Lit, Vue, Svelte, and React. I eventually landed on Stencil.js. My experience was that vanilla web components became very unwieldy very quickly. It took an unreasonable amount of code to do things. JSX is your friend. It will save you time and result in smaller app payloads.

Comment: But will it save you time? 5 years down the road your vanilla code will still run without any problems. But your framework will have had 5 new versions, so how much does a yearly upgrade cost?? And those who remember the Angular 2 "upgrade" can tell you what happens when the framework shit hits the fan

Comment: I would most likely re-write any code that's 5+ years old anyway. Code from that era wouldn't make use of ES module `import`, async `await`, JS classes, `for...of` loops, or lots of other great ES features.  It would have supported IE users and likely would be one giant JS file.

Over enough time, even vanilla JS code will start producing warnings and errors in the console.  Coding techniques that were once commonplace becomes security vulnerabilities.

You make some valid points about technical debt for sure, and I don't disagree with you, but the ES/JS language itself evolves too.